# Regex to select text that's not wrapped in paragraph even if it contains a div

Tags: regex

I want to locate starting text that's not wrapped in a paragraph.

Here's the pattern I want to identify:

1. Starts with DATA[
2. Then optional DIV
3. Then 0 or more spaces
4. Until the first P

So these lines should be selected:

```
DATA[<div> Lorem ipsum <p>..
DATA[Lorem ipsum <p>..
```

And exclude these:

```
DATA[<p>Lorem ipsum</p>..
DATA[<div><p>Lorem ipsum</p>..
DATA[<div> <p>Lorem ipsum</p>..
```

After researching online, here's the query I came up with, but it selects all of the lines including ones I want to exclude:

```
(DATA\[(<div>(\s)*)?)(?!<p).+?<p>
```

Can someone guide me where I may have gone wrong please?

Comment: if you are using language supporting `pcre` I suggest you to use `atomic groups` like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/vC1dK1/2)** or possessive quantifiers

Comment: anyway, your question contradicts your example..you are telling to find upto first `<p>`

Comment: Hi @rock321987, I'm using Sublime Text editor. Though an online editor would work for me too [link](http://regexr.com/3dfni)

Comment: then, it will work in that case

Comment: Hi rock, to clarity, the text has multiple paragraphs. Often, the first paragraph is not wrapped around the P tag. So my logic is to match any text that doesn't start with a P tag, until the next P tag. But perhaps there's a better logic for this.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks so much rock (you rock!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** :- It will work only on engine supporting `PCRE`

You can use `atomic group` like

```
(DATA\[(?>(<div>)?\s*)).+?<p>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC1dK1/2)**

***Atomic groups*** cuts down backtracking. So, the part of atomic group will either fail or succeed as a single unit.

You can also use possessive quantifiers

```
(DATA\[((<div>)?\s*)*+).+?<p>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC1dK1/3)**